# How to get a specific tr in an html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I am trying to show selected values of a dropdown in my ui.

```
<tr class="odd" rowid="1" height="50">          
        <td>
          <select disabled name="item[]" id="item_1" class="dropdown required" tabindex="18">
        <?php echo $itemOption;?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td >
          <a href="javascript:void(0);"  style="height:40px; width:45px"  class="button add_new_row ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-focus" data-role="button" ><span class="ui-button-text" style="padding:0;" disabled>+</span></a>                            
        </td>           
</tr>
```

and in jquery I need to get this tr for replicating my dropdown. Here is my jquery

```
 var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');   
 newid=parseInt(thisRow.attr('rowid'))+1;
 var count = $('.dataTable input.timepicker').length + 1;
 newRow = thisRow.clone(true).insertAfter(thisRow).find('input').val('').end().
```

But I am getting undefined for thisRow. What may be the reason. Some one please correct me.

Comment: what do `this` refers to?

Comment: I am trying to get the current object. that means current page. Dont know whether it is write or not.

Comment: @django BUT what returns `console.log(this);`??? You need to provide more context regarding your posted code because no one else knows what `this` is referring to...  Maybe what you just need is `var thisRow = $('tr[rowid=1]);`. But still beware, because this TR has descendant with ID set (`item_1`), adding clone in DOM will result in invalid HTML markup, getting some multiple elements with same ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call this script using any action like bind up in function or `trigger` on any `event` etc.

Where you want to call this??

Let have an example, suppose I have a HTML like

```
<div id="div1">
    <span class="test">Call Closest Division</span>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <span class="test">Call Closest Division</span>
</div>
```

and I want to get `closest` division when click on `span`. My script look like this

```
$('.test').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
  alert(id);
})
```

Don't forgot to include `jquery` library.

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/c49aqngm/)

Comment: Nice explanation. working fine now. Some basics I missed got from your comment. thanks a lot

Comment: then why you should not vote up and mark as answer? this will helpful to other users.